# Animation in C# using several PNGs

Tags: c#, animation, png, sprite, picturebox

I'm trying to make a click event that triggers an animation. I've drawn all of the frames and saved them as separate PNG files (all of them are 38 pixels long and 56 pixels wide), but I can't figure out how to run them through a PictureBox.

I've looked at lots of posts (here and elsewhere) where people talk about timers, but I haven't been able to figure out how to call any of these long examples from my click event. Alternatively, I exported the frames as [a single animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDf8V.gif), but GIFs always loop, and I only want the animation to play once.

Here's what I have:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int delay = 100;
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame1;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame2;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame3;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame4;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame5;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame6;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame7;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    box1.Image = Project.Properties.Resources.frame8;
    //(and so on)
}
```

This waits for about a second and then abruptly switches to the last frame (frame8 in this example), no matter what the delay variable is.

I'm probably approaching this completely wrong. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually ended up doing was googling all around for the "process itself should be in separate thread" tip-off in the first answer and following [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9naReRXp9eM). What I did was put

```
using System.Threading;
```

at the beginning of my code, put

```
Thread animationThread;
```

before all of the main events, put

```
animationThread = new Thread(back2front_card1);
animationThread.Start();
```

in the click event, and put all of the box1.Image and delay commands in this:

```
public void back2front_card1()
{
}
```

This runs the animation perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Event Handler blocks main thread. UI refreshes in main thread.

So, you click on button, event handler blocks thread and executes, and whatever you change won't be affected on UI until event handler finishes - that's exactly what you experience.

So in your button click event handler you need to *initiate* process, but process itself should be in separate thread. Easiest way, if you use frame by frame animation, is to use timers.

You need to set interval in timer, and in timer tick event you need load new image in picture box. You need to track current frame index via separate variable. If inside tick event you realize that it was the last image - set timer to disabled. Reset timer and frame variable in button click event.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't know the first thing about timers, though. I've looked over this - http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer -, but I don't know what any of it means.

Comment: I assume you are using winforms, so all you need is to add Timer component to your form, then double click it to create Timer handler. Then you need to create class variable to handle frame index.

Comment: All right. I pasted all of the Image and delay commands into the new timer1_Tick event, and put "timer1_Tick();" in the click event. It's underlined this reference like it wants input variables of some sort.

Comment: You shouldn't call `timer_Tick` directly, you should make it active OR inactive. When timer is active (it's property `Enabled` is `True`), then it generates `timer_Tick` event by itslef via `Interval` in ms (which is another timer property). So timer should be disabled by default, in button click you need to enable it, and in last timer tick you need to disable timer again.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier, I had to go to bed. I put "timer1.Start();" in the click event, and "timer1.Stop();" after all of the stuff from before. It's still pausing for a second and skipping to the last frame. What am I doing wrong?